# scheduling start up doesn't work

Tags: django, celery, celerybeat

When setting-up Celery and I want to use scheduling **do I add both init scripts** below or just the **celerybeat** one?

https://github.com/ask/celery/blob/master/contrib/generic-init.d/celeryd

https://raw.github.com/ask/celery/master/contrib/generic-init.d/celerybeat

The issue is I have both scripts and Celery does not run in beat mode and scheduling does not work (normal task do?)

Comment: I removed the django and ubuntu tags, as the question is more about celery and celerybeat.

Comment: I still relates to Django because I should have said that's the context I'm using it in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run:

```
sh -x /etc/init.d/celeryd start
```

This should print to screen any errors on startup, from this you should see whats going wrong.